# How do I show an error page when users visit my site using Microsoft Edge?

Tags: user-agent, microsoft-edge

When a user loads my website in Microsoft Edge, I need to show a page like in the below image:

> [image]

I can see like this page when I'm trying to access sites like `www.naver.com` or `www.daum.net` on Edge.

That page looks like a Provided from Microsoft , and I guess there are 
Any Javascript function to call this pages

I need to know how ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any method for opening specific web app by Internet Explorer from MS Edge browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241236/is-there-any-method-for-opening-specific-web-app-by-internet-explorer-from-ms-ed)

Comment: Hi John, if my answer was helpful it would be great if you could flag my answer as correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If possible you should avoid browser detection and move to modern web technologies that work across browsers. A great tool you can use is the sitescan on http://dev.modern.ie/tools/staticscan/ that helps to identify common issues, like outdated js libraries or css prefixes.

If your app requires legacy technology like activeX or other IE specifics you can:

- have your site added to to compatiblity list managed by Microsoft
  (for public sites)
- or create an enterprise site list for your company / intranet
  pages which determines which pages to open in IE instead of Edge.

Charles provided some details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31283160/5138360

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Regardless whether you think the idea is good or not, you need to provide an *answer* to the question.

Comment: The answer to your question is the second paragraph. The only ways to get the default message from your screenshot are a) having you site added to the global compatibility list or b) manage your own list for your company's users. Both ways will trigger the message you described. You can't trigger the message from the page itself. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: The second paragraph does not seem practical if its only for a few computers (or one).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you're going about this the wrong way, I know supporting new browsers may be frustrating, but you're only delaying work that needs to be done (in this case, supporting Edge when Internet Explorer's usage will be at a decline in the next few years).

However, what you're asking can be done with PHP's `get_browser()` function; you should check if the user-agent string has `537.36 Edge` present, and if so show the error message; if not show the normal content:

```
<?php 
    if (strpos(get_browser(),'537.36 Edge') !== false) {
        echo "Edge Browser Detected";
    }
    else
    {
       echo "You are not running Edge.";
    }

?>
```

Where `echo "Edge Browser Detected";`, replace with your error page, where `echo "You are not running Edge.";`, replace with your normal page content.

If you receive this error, [refer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3299149/2422013) on how to fix:

> WARNING get_browser() [function.get-browser]: browscap ini directive not set on line number 2

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in this thread: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_internet-insider_spartan/ms-edge-show-alert-titled-this-website-needs/7771eb86-7b4d-440c-bc4d-43a88d1e489d

You may run a scan of your site here: http://dev.modern.ie/tools/staticscan/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fnaver.com

When you do so, there's an information message regarding the "Rendering Mode":

> There is an issue with this website that could force an old rendering
>   mode.
>
> **We’ve found that this webpage was added to a Compatibility View list
>   when a user reported a compatibility issue while browsing in Microsoft
>   Edge**. For this reason, your site will render in Internet Explorer 11
>   on Windows 10 as a fallback. We recommend that you use modern markup
>   for all modern browsers and include Microsoft Edge in your test
>   matrix.

So there you go, it seems that the website needs to be reported as incompatible for Edge to display this message. However, i'd be surprised if Microsoft added all reported sites to their compatibility list (I bet the site has to be of some significance and several users need to report the site).

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31283160/1010492 on how to have your site added to the compatibility list.