# Force page to open in Internet explorer (Not edge/spartan)

Tags: html, internet-explorer

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Mimic Internet Explorer 7 -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE8" />
  <title>Plania 7.3 Redirector</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Content goes here.</p>
 <meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="5; url=/PlaniaWS/LoginPage.aspx">
</body>
</html>
```

My Company has a old web Product where the old Version requires Internet Explorer 8.

Using compatebility worked just fine, but With Windows 10 and Edge(Spartan) this no longer Works.
I have noticed other pages are able to make Edge(Spartan) generate the following Message to the user.

How do you make that happen?

I have tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Mimic Internet Explorer 7 -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE8" />
  <title>Plania 7.3 Redirector</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Content goes here.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot of the "error Message" that Edge(spartan) can give users.

EDIT:
Im aware the this is not a good long term solution, the New Version of the Product does not have any browser dependency. But i want to provide support for the old Version so it Works With updates OS.

[image]

Comment: You cannot force a page to open on a specific browser. Is your question: "how to display the 'this website needs Internet Explorer'" message when opening the page on Edge?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31538683/how-do-i-show-an-error-page-when-users-visit-my-site-using-microsoft-edge

Comment: @GyumFox Thats correct. I want that spesific error Message.

I would say its not a duplicate, because the Message i show in the screenshot is built in to IE, not a custom "use different browser" Message.

Comment: I don't think that the message you are seeing is a custom one. I think the message on the screenshot was just for an older version of Edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be impossible before, but it is possible now with IE 11.

The answer is using **Enterprise mode for IE11**. I believe you  find all you need from here:
[Use Enterprise Mode to improve compatibility](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/microsoft-edge/emie-to-improve-compatibility)

There are two versions of Enterprise Mode schema (v.1 and v.2), it is recommended to use v.2 as suggested by [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/enterprise-mode-schema-version-2-guidance).

Below is something not easy to be found:

### Make Enterprise mode for IE11 work on Windows 7

Current latest version of IE11 on Windows 7 is

- version 11.0.9600.17483 (update version 11.0.20)

To make that IE11 work with Enterprise mode , you must install at least [cumulative update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140847/update-to-improve-enterprise-mode-in-internet-explorer-11) - [KB3160005 for Windows 7](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/ms16-063).

### Open all intranet sites with IE

You  forward all intranet over to IE, by enabling this policy:

**Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Microsoft Edge\Sends all intranet traffic over to Internet Explorer**

This feature works when you input http://site-name format in Edge address bar.

**Note**: After testing, if URL includes domain name, like http://site-name.contoso.com, Edge will open the site inside itself.

[image: Sends all intranet traffic over to Internet Explorer]

Comment: Just because you can does not mean you should