# How can I force Edge to prompt needIE for my own site

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

My own site need to run in IE.
But some user opened it in Microsoft Edge. How Can I make the Edge prompt needIE page or how can I Lunch IE in Edge?

Comment: Analyse the user agent string sent by the browser.

Comment: I know I can get browser info from user agent. But how can I make Edge display need IE error page or lunchIE automatically in Edge?

Comment: Then it would help a lot, if you at least specified the language you deliver your site in - or you cannot expect any concrete help at all. Also, this is not a "write me an arbitrary solution" site, but some work and research on the questioner's part is expected to be shown, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot:) . I know Edge will prompt needIE if a web site is in Cloud CV List automatically, and it will invoke  window.external.LaunchIE("url”, false) to open link in IE. But I don't know how to add my site to MS Cloud CV list, and I also can't invoke the function which Edge use with permission error.

Comment: What site functionality do you need IE for rather than MS Edge? The better long term plan is to remove those dependancies when you can.

Comment: Add a blank ActiveX control to the site.

Comment: You could write some `php` to detect the browser (perhaps using plugins) and use an `if` statement to determine what to display. I'm sure if you Google search for that, you will find that people already did similar things.

Comment: The question is too broad -- The best solution will depend on what the problem is; tell us what specific feature(s) your site is using that require IE and don't work in Edge. For example, if you're using an ActiveX control, your solution may be to put some kind of fallback text into the markup that is displayed when the control fails to load. This text could tell the user what browser versions they need to use. Other features may need a different approach.

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that if your site works in IE but not Edge, then it probably also doesn't work in other modern browsers. Which means that Mac users, Chromebook users, or users with an IOS or Android device probably can't see your site either. If your site is on the public internet, then you really do need to fix that. And if it's a private site on an intranet, then you should be able to tell users what browser to use anyway, so there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I show an error page when users visit my site using Microsoft Edge?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31538683/how-do-i-show-an-error-page-when-users-visit-my-site-using-microsoft-edge)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Enterprise Mode Site List Manager.

There's a good [overview article](http://www.techradar.com/us/news/software/how-to-set-up-enterprise-mode-and-edge-to-launch-internet-explorer-1306406) on techradar with more details on when and how to use it.

Comment: This is why it's better to put the actual answer in your response, rather than linking.  Here's a Web Archive link that works: https://web.archive.org/web/20161031121151/http://www.techradar.com/news/software/how-to-set-up-enterprise-mode-and-edge-to-launch-internet-explorer-1306406